# laravel framework errors when i need run servers

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have a problem about install laravel framework and is need to run php server show this errors is not common error

```
Warning: require(C:\wamp64\www\madresamoon\img\app/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:
\wamp64\www\madresamoon\img\app\artisan on line 18

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\wamp64\www\madresamoon\img\app/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php
\pear') in C:\wamp64\www\madresamoon\img\app\artisan on line 18
```

Comment: Have you done `composer update`? and set the proper permissions?

Comment: Please provide the step by step process of what you did including (a) How did you install Laravel (b) how are you running the PHP server. Laravel has its own method of running the built-in server which you can run via `php artisan serve` and it should work for most cases. You seem to be trying to run the built-in server from a place other than the root which might cause issues

Comment: have you done ```composer install```

Answer (score 0):

composer update or install can solve this and donot forget

```
php artisan config:cache
```

after composer install

Answer (score 0):

- First, delete `vendor` folder in your project direcotry.
- then, run `composer install`

Hope this will work for you!